# KPI for Mobile app

Tags: performance, testing, mobile, kpi

What KPI(Key Performance Indicators) should we keep in mind while testing a mobile app or what can be the KPIs for a successful mobile app?

Comment: Any programming language. My question is what specific indicators show your app's high performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KPIs for Apps on mobile devices:

- Application time running without connection to permanent power (battery) (App + device + OS)
- Frequency of connections to server (every 5, 10, 30 minutes)
- Num bytes needeed for App data packet to server.
- storage capacity for app data
- logging capacity before roll over
- time intervall app can fully work whitout connection to server

Unclear if these are KPIs:

- remote updateable (full update, difference update)
- capable to migrate app data persisted with old app version to new one.
- encryption of app data.

Answer (score 0):

KPI's to measure Success of Mobile App

1. Downloads
2. Active Users - monthly and daily
3. Revenue per User
4. Acquisition Cost
5. Retention Rate
6. User Experience - App Launch time/ Social Shares / Pages visited
7. Session Time